# Can I run mongoimport as a part of Jenkins build step

Tags: mongodb, jenkins, import

I am running a job which produces a json output file and I want to dump the file contents into mongo as a part of build step but when I run mongoimport the job fails saying mongoimport command not found

Below is the command am using as a part of build step shell script:

'''mongoimport --uri "dbString" --drop --collection col-name --file file-path-in-workspace -- jsonArray'''